# One or multiple databases per Docker container

Tags: mysql, database, docker

Let's say I have several different containers and each one of them uses it's own database. What is the best practice in this case regarding performance? Run one container, say a MySQL server, with all the databases in there or run one database server container per database?

Any other comment besides the performance would be welcome.

Comment: Performance rule #1 - the less work CPU / HDD do, the faster the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Docker container overhead is not significant and negligible here, the question is more about architecture in a microservices paradigm.

Performance is indeed a complex question and there is no general advice, but maybe the following will help you:

Personally, I doubt that at the beginning of the project one should try to solve all possible performance problems in advance (#*MVP*, #*agile*)
However, correct me, but it looks like you have not many resources (one host?) and want to be thrifty with these resources in advance.

Ok, what is your biggest concern now?

### RAM is a concern

Then having two concurrent MySQL instances **on the same host** is maybe not that good (but not a problem for different setups)

For one host I would propose to start using one Database container but create different schemas.
It might involve additional work with standard container (https://forums.docker.com/t/multiple-databases-in-official-mysql-container/8324)

### Other concerns

I would not care too much now and start with separate databases from the beginning.
Being able to separate your services horizontal to the databases is a huge value! I would not want to weaken this design decision because of very theoretical future performance issues.

Comment: My problem is neither memory nor performance. Currently I am serving 5 apps in 7 containers at an Ubuntu 14.04 server and they work like a charm. I want to know what is the best practice because in the near future I will be serving 20 or 30 apps (5-10 databases) and maybe performance problems will arise. Deploying the apps in the "correct" way could save me lots of trouble in the future. 
By memory I guess you mean RAM, given that memory that docker uses is insignificant for an HDD, right?

Comment: Yes i mean RAM. This is the point i would look on. And there is no "correct" way you can agrue for one or other it depends on weight you put on "memory" argument or on "cleaner" more isolated design you ran so far.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use a single database server, preferably running a shell you can attach to for administration, sharing either a Unix socket, a port or both to linked containers. This means you'll have an easier time managing the database container as a service, tweaking performances, monitoring usage, backing up volumes, etc.

Granted, there might be non-standard situations where you might want to have independent servers, for instance running servers with isolated host resources, users, databases, though I'm certain this shouldn't apply to developer environments.

Comment: I'm sorry, -1 for me.  "Running servers with isolated host resources ... shouldn't apply to developer environments" is very much not true.  I use Docker precisely because it isolates things on my system, and I spend far less time playing with the active Dev Deployment that my boss sees to debug bullshit environment settings.  What if the code you write ends up depending on using the same server?  It can be hard to track that down, especially if you have to wait for CI/CD between each temporary debugging change.

Comment: What if you're still running everything together on your development machine, and the server is running everything together for a few years, and then your boss decides you need to split up the hosting for the Wordpress site and for the API which both were accessing databases on the same container?  Suddenly the Live Dev Server doesn't work anymore, and if you're still running them together, you can't figure out why.