# docker-compose with multiple databases

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out how to implement docker using docker-compose.yml with 2 databases imported from sql dumps.

```
httpd:
    container_name: webserver
    build: ./webserver/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - mysql
        - mysql2
    volumes_from:
        - app

mysql:
    container_name: sqlserver
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    volumes:
        - ./sqlserver:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname1
        MYSQL_USER: dbuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass

mysql2:
    extends: mysql
    container_name: sqlserver2
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname2
        MYSQL_USER: dbuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass

app:
    container_name: webdata
    image: php:latest
    volumes:
        - ../php:/var/www/html
    command: "true"
```

The above returns the following:

```
Kronos:mybuild avanche$ ./run.sh 
Creating sqlserver
Creating webdata
Creating sqlserver2

ERROR: for mysql2  driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sqlserver2 (6cae3dfe7997d3787a8d59a95c1b5164f7431041c1394128c14e5ae8efe647a8): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 63, in main
AttributeError: 'ProjectError' object has no attribute 'msg'
docker-compose returned -1
```

Basically, I'm trying to get my whole stack setup in a single docker compose file, create 2 databases and import the respective sql dumps.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: but what`s the problem?

Comment: Basically, I understand it's creating another mysql container, but I don't see how to make it reuse the same container and simply add another db.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just as an update to anyone else who may look into this.

I solved this by removing:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
```

from **docker-compose.yml** and adding the relevant create database statements directly to the sql file being passed to **docker-entrypoint-initdb.d**.

At that stage, sql commands are performed under root, so you'll also need to add a statement to grant relevant permissions to the database user you want to use.

Comment: Could you paste the full docket compose please

Comment: @david_adler https://stackoverflow.com/a/68714439/397872

Answer (score 126):

#### Multiple databases in a single Docker container

The answers elsewhere on this page set up a dedicated container for each database, but a single MySQL server is capable of hosting multiple databases. Whether you should [is a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762709/one-or-multiple-databases-per-docker-container), but if you want multiple databases in a single container, [here's an example](https://github.com/abagayev/docker-bootstrap-collection/tree/master/mysql-few-databases).

*docker-compose.yml:*

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
        - ./docker/provision/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: local
```

*docker/provision/mysql/init/01-databases.sql:*

```
# create databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `primary`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `secondary`;

# create root user and grant rights
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'local';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

#### How does this work?

This works because the [MySQL Docker project](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql) has an [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/333935aa6612376d58737a8cab0e3f5df370585a/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L197) that will run through all files in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder, if it exists. This is useful for setting up databases and initializing their schema and data. In docker-compose, we're using `volumes` to map that virtual folder to a folder on the host system.

Comment: (Note this was edited to use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`; personally I prefer just `GRANT ALL` since it's more concise and functionally identical (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges) but I won't bother lobbying to revert it.)

Comment: can you also tell it's equivalent for PostgreSQL?

Comment: you can also add shell scripts with the extension .sh in that dir

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation in your example code? `services` is a top level key, and not nested under `volumes` (see your example link). Right now this will error out saying that the `db` key 'does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'' (docker 3.7)

Comment: @Cosmin That seems reasonable. You can edit it yourself if you like.

Comment: Is there any way to delete all files under ```/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d``` folder after the execution?

Comment: how to change the schema only for table inside the `secondary` database ? Thanks

Comment: @jaden they are completely separate databases with their own schema. There's no copying or  replicating here.

Comment: Look guys, I just did what this answer tell me to do, but I figured a problem that I HAD, If you create a root user using the SQL file (01-databases.sql) you'll got a error, because this root user was already created by MySql docker image when you setup MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD env . You need to create only your application user that you'll use in your database application connection options.

Comment: n my case, I just did this: 

`## create databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks_management`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks_management_tests`;

## create application user and grant rights
CREATE USER 'taskmanager'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dGFza21hbmFnZXJwYXNzd29yZA==';
GRANT ALL ON tasks_management.* TO 'taskmanager'@'%';
GRANT ALL ON tasks_management_tests.* TO 'taskmanager'@'%';`

Comment: This solution looks great, but I couldn't get it to run. The system successfully creates several databases, but there are problems with access to them, which I have not been able to resolve.

Comment: The user is created at localhost but privileges are granted from any host including external IP.
1) I would prefer consistency so host is either 'localhost' or '%' in both cases
2) In my experience docker is using random IPs for connection to DB internally so wildcard '%' is preferable for docker at development environment (not production)

Answer (score 28):

You're trying to bind both database containers to the same port - `3306`. Which is essentially impossible.
You need to change the port-mapping for one of the databases, for example `mysql` keeps `3306:3306`, and `mysql2` should use `3307:3306`.

Comment: adding: ports: -3307:3306 didn't resolve it. Same error. Does it ignore ports on extended containers maybe?

Comment: @Avanche I suppose it does ignore. Here is a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2260

Comment: Thanks, I'll just have to go and do it in the dockerfile unfortunately

Comment: Replace this "image: mysql:latest" with "image: mysql:latest" with different port configuration, then check

Answer (score 27):

After struggling, 3 days found this [Article](https://medium.com/@onexlab.io/docker-compose-mysql-multiple-database-fe640938e06b)
to solve this issue saved my life

File Structure

```
Project
├── docker-compose.yml (File)
├── init (Directory)
│   ├── 01.sql (File)
```

then point init directory inside the volumes in the docker-compose.yml file as following

```
volumes: 
  - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

01.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`;
GRANT ALL ON `test`.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
    
services: 
    # MySQL
    db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: user

        volumes: 
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

Comment: what if we only wanna connect to `test` database and change the schema there, do you have any idea how to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: thank you, i follow the article and it works

Answer (score 10):

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql1:
    image: mysql:5.6.26
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdf
     MYSQL_USER: asdf
     MYSQL_HOST: localhost
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: asdf
     MYSQL_DATABASE: asdf
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  mysql2:
    image: mysql:5.6.26
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdf
     MYSQL_USER: asdf
     MYSQL_HOST: localhost
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: asdf
     MYSQL_DATABASE: asdf
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
```

- After `docker-compose up`
- Connect to mysql1

  ```
  mysql -h localhost -uasdf -P 3307 -pasdf asdf --protocol=tcp -D asdf
  ```
- Connect to mysql2

  ```
  mysql -h localhost -uasdf -P 3308 -pasdf asdf --protocol=tcp -D asdf
  ```

Comment: Can you please have different values for `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_DATABASE` instead of `asdf` so that your **Connect to mysql** command have more clarity. 
All `asdf` values is a little confusing. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Run multiple services in a container**

From my point of view none of the answers above are complete. In original question,
I see an attempt to start two containers. Is it good or bad to run two database containers? Docker documentation says

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using one service per container.
> That service may fork into multiple processes (for example, Apache web server starts multiple worker processes). It’s ok to have multiple processes,
> but to get the most benefit out of Docker, avoid one container being responsible for multiple aspects of your overall application.
> You can connect multiple containers using user-defined networks and shared volumes.

It seems like logically correct to apply the same rule to databases as well. So, there is nothing wrong to use database container per schema. It gives flexibility.

Below I added networks and fixed databases initialisation in more
elegant way. By extending 'mysql' container the same 3306 port is exposed as external to
provide access to mysql database from console or external applications.
That port must be unique. To fix this error I added port mapping for
mysql2 container as well. These ports provides access to databases from
console or external applications. If databases access required from app
container only, these mappings are not needed. Docker has its own
internal DNS. That's why database connections for app container can be
configured by using container names as domain names. So, database
connection strings will be dbuser@mysql:3306/dbname1 and
dbuser@mysql2:3306/dbname2.

```
version: '3'
services:

 httpd:
    container_name: webserver
    build: ./webserver/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - mysql
        - mysql2
    volumes_from:
        - app
   
 mysql:
    container_name: sqlserver
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    volumes:
        - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname1
        MYSQL_USER: dbuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
    networks:
      - app-network
   
 mysql2:
    extends: mysql
    container_name: sqlserver2
    ports:
        - 3307:3306
    volumes:
        - ./dump2.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname2
        MYSQL_USER: dbuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
   networks:
      - app2-network

 app:
    container_name: webdata
    image: php:latest
    volumes:
        - ../php:/var/www/html
    command: "true"
    networks:
      - app-network
      - app2-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
  app2-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: this answer is really good

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container

Answer (score 5):

you can have multiple databases in a single container service:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres-db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./db-prod.env
```

`db-prod.env`

```
POSTGRES_USER=myusername
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=db1,db2
```

Sources :

- [GitHub | Docker PostgresSQL Multiple Databases](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases)
- [Dev.To | Multiple Postgres Databases in a single Docker Container](https://dev.to/bgord/multiple-postgres-databases-in-a-single-docker-container-417l)
- [Stack Overflow | Multiple databases in docker and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668342/6484358)

Answer (score 3):

When you study the `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` of the mysql image, you will notice different modes of treating `*.sh` files in your mapped `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (look for **`HERE`** markers):

```
        case "$f" in
            *.sh)
                if [ -x "$f" ]; then
                    "$f"
                else
                    . "$f" # HERE!!
                fi
                ;;
            *.sql)    mysql_note "$0: running $f"; docker_process_sql < "$f"; echo ;; # HERE!!
            # ...
        esac
```

With this you can create a `000-databases.sh` without the executable bit, containing the following:

```
echo "
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`other-database\`;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`other-database\`.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD';
" | docker_process_sql
```

The key utility here is **`docker_process_sql`**, which handles SQL scripts. The `MYSQL_*` variables come from your `docker-compose.yml` environment config.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, and will try this. Are there any docs which describe this behavior/specific use case, other than review of docker-entrypoint.sh?

Comment: Totally different problem here with the `docker_process_sql` command but search brought me here. I was trying to pipe an output from an `.sh` file which was `chmod 777`. When I removed the executable bit `chmod 666` the command `docker_process_sql` worked just fine. Thanks for the detailed mysql image code explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For me, helped next:

```
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: mgt_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mgtdb
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  db2:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pay_vault_db 
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: payvaultdb
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
```

Answer (score 1):

Some answers mentioned to place .sql files in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory in order to create the extra databases. However, this approach requires the database names to be hardcoded in the sql file.

Fortunately, upon examining the source code of the entrypoint.sh script in both the [mysql](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/f4030aebf6a63d640f7085fb3e4601b4e70313c8/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) and [postgresql](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/8a631b939a0b4197cb6bef49b50b6c40c80ddf5b/15/bookworm/docker-entrypoint.sh) image, it was discovered that files under the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory can be not only sql files, but also shell scripts. Therefore, .sh files can be placed in this directory. As a result, environment variables can be used in the script without having to hardcode them.

Additionally, if the script file is not executable, it will be sourced instead of invoked. This means that functions defined in the entrypoint.sh script can be reused directly!

So here comes the solution:

docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
  image: "mysql:8.0"
  command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
    MORE_DATABASES: db2 db3
  volumes:
    - ./docker/provision/mysql/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

postgres:
  image: "postgres:15"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: dev
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev
    POSTGRES_DB: db1
    MORE_DATABASES: db2 db3
  volumes:
    - ./docker/provision/postgres/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

docker/provision/mysql/init/01-create-more-databases.sh

```
# Keep this file plain. Do not `chmod +x` to make it executable.

create_more_databases() {
    local databases=( $MORE_DATABASES )
    local db
    for db in "${databases[@]}"; do
        mysql_note "Creating database ${db}"
        docker_process_sql --database=mysql <<<"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$db\` ;"

        if [ -n "$MYSQL_USER" ] && [ -n "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ]; then
            mysql_note "Giving user ${MYSQL_USER} access to schema ${db}"
            docker_process_sql --database=mysql <<<"GRANT ALL ON \`${db//_/\\_}\`.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' ;"
        
        fi
    done
}

if [ -n "$MORE_DATABASES" ]; then
    create_more_databases
fi
```

docker/provision/postgres/init/01-create-more-databases.sh

```
# Keep this file plain. Do not `chmod +x` to make it executable.

create_more_databases() {
    local databases=( $MORE_DATABASES )
    local db
    for db in "${databases[@]}"; do
        POSTGRES_DB="$db" docker_setup_db
    done
}

if [ -n "$MORE_DATABASES" ]; then
    create_more_databases
fi
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. However when I run docker compose up with this setup, I am getting following error if casdoor.sh file is not executable: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 80: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/casdoor.sh: Permission denied. Any clue on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution below, which creates two docker containers with a DB in each.

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
volumes:
  db-vol:
  hist-vol:

services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:12.11
    container_name: live-db-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd
      POSTGRES_USER: usr
      POSTGRES_DB: live-db
    volumes:
      - db-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  pgsql-hist:
    image: postgres:12.11
    container_name: hist-db-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd
      POSTGRES_USER: usr
      POSTGRES_DB: hist-db
    volumes:
      - hist-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/histdata
    ports:
      - 3306:5432

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
      - pgsql-hist
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

networks:
  talk: {}
```

Then when creating engines to initialise and connect to the databases, use the following connection strings:

```
live_url = "postgresql+psycopg2://usr:pwd@live-db-container:5432/live-db"
hist_url = "postgresql+psycopg2://usr:pwd@hist-db-container:5432/hist-db"
```

Note that the ports specified are the same (5432) in the urls! They are mapped differently in the .yml file though (5432 --> 5432) and (3306 --> 5432). Using sqlalchemy_utils' create_engine on these urls should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working piece of code.

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: db-service               
    restart: on-failure
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file:
       - 'docker.env'    
    networks:
      - ektamart-tier
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql   
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

Structure:

```
- docker-compose.yml
- docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   |- init.sql
```

Code inside init.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS user_service_db;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS order_service_db;
```

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate the two MySQL databases (`almitsolutions_auth_db` and `almitsolutions_universal_db`) in your Dockerized Application, you have a few options. You can either use a single MySQL container with multiple databases or use separate containers for each database. For simplicity and resource efficiency, I'll demonstrate the single container approach for a Django Rest Framework Backend that uses two databases.

#### Adjusting the Docker Compose File

Modify the `docker-compose.yml` file to create two databases within the same MySQL container:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_USER: almdatabasehandler
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  # Other services (rabbitmq, web, celery) as before

volumes:
  mysql_data:
  # Other volumes as before
```

In this configuration, both databases will be hosted within the `db` container. You'll need to create the databases manually or through a script.

#### Adjusting Django Settings

Modify your Django `settings.py` to connect to the correct host:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'almitsolutions_auth_db',
        'USER': 'almdatabasehandler',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'db',  # Use the MySQL service name from docker-compose.yml
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'universal': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'almitsolutions_universal_db',
        'USER': 'almdatabasehandler',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'db',  # Use the MySQL service name from docker-compose.yml
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

#### Creating Databases

You have a few options to create these databases:

1. **Manually**: After starting the MySQL container, connect to it using a MySQL client and manually create both databases.
2. **Initialization Script**: Place a SQL script in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory in the MySQL container. Any `.sql` or `.sh` scripts in this directory will be automatically executed upon container startup. Example:

```sql
-- init-db.sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS almitsolutions_auth_db;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS almitsolutions_universal_db;
```

Include the script in your Docker Compose setup:

```yaml
db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./path/to/init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql
  # Other configurations as before
```

#### Running the Services

Run `docker-compose up` to start all services. This setup will ensure that your Django application can connect to the correct databases hosted within the same MySQL container.

#### Note

- Ensure that the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` in the `docker-compose.yml` is secure, especially if you're going to use this setup in a production or publicly accessible environment.
- Adjust the `command` parameter for MySQL as per your MySQL version and authentication requirements.
- Consider using environment variables for sensitive data like database passwords.