# Multiple PostgreSQL database creation in a docker-compose file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm building an app using PostgreSQL ... But I need 2 DB's ... Is there an easy way to add 2 DB's using the same username / password / host? One called API and one called TESTING

My current docker-compose DB setup is as follows;

```
# PostgreSQL Service
postgresql:
image: postgres
container_name: postgresql
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=dev
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=development1234
  - POSTGRES_DB=api
  - SERVICE_TAGS=dev
  - PGDATA=/tmp
volumes:
  - ./dev/dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  - app-network
```

Comment: Similar question [Multiple databases in docker and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46668233/8482479)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple databases in docker and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668233/multiple-databases-in-docker-and-docker-compose)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to create a separate init script to create the second database.  Assuming you are using `POSTGRES_DB=api` as listed, you can create a script `create_second_db.sh` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE testing;
EOSQL
```

Then, put `create_second_db.sh` in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`:

```
...
volumes:
  - ./dev/dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./create_second_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_second_db.sh
...
```

Bear in mind as [per the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), "scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty"

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. Im getting the following `CREATE DATABASE
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_second_db.sh
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 141: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_second_db.sh: Is a directory
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization`

Comment: The scripts worked on my end.  Based on the error you pasted, it seems that your cluster already exists at `./dev/dbdata` and therefore the scripts are getting skipped.

Comment: Ahh yes, I had to kill the volume and re up the container. Worked perfect :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./docker-postgresql-multiple-databases:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=db1,postgres:db2,postgres:db3,postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

and in folder `docker-postgresql-multiple-databases` you should have script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

function create_user_and_database() {
    local database=$(echo $1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk  '{print $1}')
    local owner=$(echo $1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk  '{print $2}')
    echo "  Creating user and database '$database'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $owner;
EOSQL
}

if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ':' ' '); do
        create_user_and_database $db
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```

Comment: - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=db1,postgres:db2,postgres:db3,postgres

I did not immediately understand that the format:
db_name,db_owner with ':' as separator

Comment: I encountered an database error about not existing role. After removing the GRANG gommand it works fine. So a simpler create_database founction is enough.

Comment: you need to change: `POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=db1,postgres:db2,postgres:db3,postgres`
to
`POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=db1,postgres:db2,postgres:db3,postgres`