# create one database by docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
 #######################################
  # Kong database
  ####################################### 
  kong-database:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: kong-database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: kong
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
      DB_PASSWORD: kong
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "kong"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    restart: on-failure
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"  
    volumes:
      - kong_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

konga:
    image: pantsel/konga:next
    container_name: konga
    restart: always
    networks:
        - kong-net
    environment:
      DB_ADAPTER: postgres
      DB_HOST: kong-database
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: kong
      DB_PASSWORD: kong
      DB_DATABASE: konga_db
      POSTGRES_DB: kong
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
      TOKEN_SECRET: km1GUr4RkcQD7DewhJPNXrCuZwcKmqjb
      NODE_ENV: production
      NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
      - kong
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

I want when **Konga** service run, create one database called `konga_db`

how can I handle this problem in docker-compose?

Comment: You already have one database is `kong` and you want to create one more inside `kong-database` container or what? I don't know why you want to achieve it but it makes no sense to me. Cuz if you stop `konga` service and run it again, you have to delete `konga_db` and create a new one?

Comment: actually, when I run this docker-compose I encounter this ERROR `FATAL:  database "konga_db" does not exist` . so I decided to make this database manually with docker-composer @ToanQuocHo

Comment: With this config you're creating a database named "kong" while your other service is using the database called "konga_db", which doesn't exist. If you don't need the "kong" database, just use "kongda_db" instead as `DB_DATABASE` for the Postgres service.

Comment: @timsmelik thanks for the answer. but I need both databases

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi if you want multiple databases, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668233/multiple-databases-in-docker-and-docker-compose)