# Problem with docker-compose, django and mysql during testing

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am using docker-compose along with django and mysql, and I want in the custom entrypoint of django I want to do tests via `python manage.py test`.
Since I am connected to mysql, by default it goes to look for the database *test_NAMEDATABASE*, but it doesn't find it.
So I tried to create it as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204142/docker-compose-with-multiple-databases), but I have several problems with permissions.
I think this is a very common situation, how did you solve it?
This is my mysql service in docker-compose.yml:

```
  db:
image: mysql:latest
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
ports:
  - 3306:${MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT}
environment:
  - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
  - MYSQL_USER
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD
  - MYSQL_DATABASE
  - MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST
  - MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT
volumes:
  - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And this is my settings.py settings in django:

```
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
    'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'),   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT')
}
```

It gives me this error when I try to manually create the database *"test_NAMEDATABASE"* inside the mysql container: "Access denied for user 'django'@'%' to database 'test_NAMEDATABASE"

### Heading

Comment: Do you have values for the environment variables?  Shouldn't it be `- MYSQL_PASSWORD: password` et c.

Comment: Yes, the variables are set correctly. They are taken from the .env file I have in my project. In fact everything works if I don't do python manage.py test

Comment: Access denied means that either the username and/or the password is not correct.